# String to Array / Var Set .NET Bingo

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I have a set of thirty numbers in a DB which are all in one cell, separated by spaces.  I am evaluating them as such:

```
    <%# Eval("winning_numbers").ToString().Split(' ')[0]%>
    <%# Eval("winning_numbers").ToString().Split(' ')[1]%>
    <%# Eval("winning_numbers").ToString().Split(' ')[2]%>
```

And so forth, up to thirty (29).  This displays them all in a row.  The numbers are random up to 75, like in a bingo game.  What I would like to be able to do is to display them in a table, where if the number is between 01 and 15, it displays in the first row, 16-30 = second row, and so forth.  Where I'm stuck mentally is that there aren't a finite amount of numbers in each tier - it is totally random.  How can I do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you not just use if statements to sort the numbers?

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  Can I?

Comment: Well if the numbers can only go to 75 then yes. Just have the 5 corresponding if statements

`if(1 <= num <= 15){//put in first row}`

and so on for the 5 corresponding rows.

Comment: I'm a little lost on how to display that and make that work.  Do I have to create an array?

Comment: Well are you putting the results into a list?

Comment: Yes.  Five rows of random length.

Comment: Alright, well when once you put it into the list, use a for loop to iterate through the list. Inside the for loop have the 5 if statements to sort them into their respective columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for two-dimensional arrays, check this out:

- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of them items inside of a list then you can iterate through the list using a for loop

```
for(int I = 0; I < numlist.Count; I++)
{
     //Inside the for loop we can check the number, and see what column it will fit into.
     if(1 <= I <= 15)
     {
          //The code to put the item into the respective list.
     }
     if(16 <= I <= 30)
     {
          //The code to put the item into the respective list.
     }
     etc...
}
```